# How can I get rid of groff / nroff / troff markers?

Tags: groff

I can't find useful info how to easily delete all groff (nroff) related formatting markers. unroff doesn't seem to do the job. On Mac OS I can't see it anyway.

Comment: See if you can install [deroff](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/man/deroff.1.html) from [the Heirloom Project](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Could you share an example that `unroff` can't handle?  Also, what is `unroff` (it's not in the macOS base system, nor in Homebrew)?  Running it through `nroff` would technically delete the actual markup.

Comment: If you want normal text output for a manual page, you could do something like `man foo | col -b`.